# Context Menu Item's click not firing

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to show a message box alert when the user clicks on a MenuItem inside a context menu. Here is the context menu code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        MenuItem mni = new MenuItem();
        mni.Text = "BackLog Task";
        mni.MenuItems.Add("Backlog Task (1)");
        mni.Click += new EventHandler(this.mni_Click);

        contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add(mni);

        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon1.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon
           (System.Environment.GetFolderPath
           (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
           + @"\icon.ico");
        notifyIcon1.Text = "Right-click me!";
        notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = contextMenu1;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Here is the click event handler :

```
    void mni_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Back Log Event Handler");
    }
```

But the click event is never fired. Does any have any idea what might be wrong ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MenuItem` has descendants, that you added on:

```
mni.MenuItems.Add("Backlog Task (1)");
```

If you check [the documentation for the Click event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.click(v=vs.110).aspx) it clearly states (bold is mine):

> **If the MenuItems property for the MenuItem contains any items, this event is not raised**. This event is not raised for parent menu items.

Comment: Thanks ... that was spot on. :)